# why std::scan_is emits runtime error in visual studio compiler?

Tags: c++

The example [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ctype_char/scan_is) emits a runtime error with memory access violation in Visual Studio 2013.

```
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    auto& f = std::use_facet<std::ctype<char>>(std::locale(""));

    // skip until the first letter
    char s1[] = "      \t\t\n  Test";
    const char* p1 = f.scan_is(std::ctype_base::alpha, std::begin(s1), std::end(s1));
    std::cout << "'" << p1 << "'\n";

    // skip until the first letter
    char s2[] = "123456789abcd";
    const char* p2 = f.scan_is(std::ctype_base::alpha, std::begin(s2), std::end(s2));
    std::cout << "'" << p2 << "'\n";
}
```

Why is that? Wrong implementation from the compiler?

Comment: Unlikely there's a bug in VS. More likely that you have a bug in your code. Show us what you've tried.

Comment: If it is giving an error, chances are you're not using it right.

Comment: Verified. This example code from `cppreference.com` does crash in VS2013 update 5 when executing: `const char* p1 = f.scan_is(std::ctype_base::alpha, std::begin(s1), std::end(s1));` The crash is in the `xlocale` implementation.

Comment: @freakish: _"Unlikely there's a bug in VS"_ lol

Comment: @BoundaryImposition What's so funny about it? 99% of time when someone says there's a bug in compiler its not.

Comment: @freakish: What's funny is that Visual Studio has loads of bugs, and this is one of them.

Comment: To be fair, if I see someone with a score of 26 complaining about the compiler, I tend to assume it's them first.  The fact it was a published example helped quite a bit, though.

Comment: @Donnie: Well, hopefully this situation has reminded you of the pitfalls involved with making assumptions. :)

Comment: @BoundaryImposition - Most likely not. :)

Comment: [Throws exception on ideone](http://ideone.com/MNCwju)

Answer (score 3):

The line `auto& f = std::use_facet<std::ctype<char>>(std::locale(""));` causes the error. The reference f is an alias for a null object. It seems that this implementation works for gcc C+11 and above compilers but it does not work in Microsoft compilers. Thus the right implementation in Visual Studio 2013 & 2015 which i tested, is:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::locale loc(std::locale(""));
    //auto& f = std::use_facet<std::ctype<char>>(std::locale(""));
    auto& f = std::use_facet<std::ctype<char>>(loc);
    // skip until the first letter
    char s1[] = "      \t\t\n  Test";
    const char* p1 = f.scan_is(std::ctype_base::alpha, std::begin(s1), std::end(s1));
    std::cout << "'" << p1 << "'\n";

    // skip until the first letter
    char s2[] = "123456789abcd";
    const char* p2 = f.scan_is(std::ctype_base::alpha, std::begin(s2), std::end(s2));
    std::cout << "'" << p2 << "'\n";
}
```